# Implementing show for multi-line content in Haskell

Tags: debugging, haskell, logging, formatting, typeclass

I have a small matrix type in Haskell that is that is most appropriately displayed across multiple lines.  My current implementation of `show` formats matrices like this:

```
matFromRows [[1,2]
            ,[3,4]]
```

This works well on its own (IE for seeing the contents of a matrix in `ghci`), but whenever a matrix is displayed as part of a larger structure, it generates very awkwardly formatted and difficult to read content.  For example, the tuple `(matFromRows [[1, 2], [3, 4]], matFromRows [[5, 6], [7, 8]])` will display as

```
(matFromRows [[1,2]
            ,[3,4]],matFromRows [[5,6]
            ,[7,8]]
```

What is the most graceful way to handle `show`ing multi-line content in Haskell, so that its formatting isn't destroyed when you display it as part of a larger structure?

Comment: I'm not familiar with pretty-printing combinator libraries, but they might offer a nice solution for this task. Try to search Hackage for some usable one.

Comment: Can you add the definition of your data type and the Show instance to your question, please?

Comment: chi@ is right, you want a pretty-printing library.  The most popular is [`Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty-1.0.1.0/docs/Text-PrettyPrint-HughesPJ.html).  The `Show` class isn't quite good enough for this though, you need a class which takes `a -> Doc` instead, then convert the `Doc` to a `String` at the very end.